# If (G,*) is a group , $a,b\in G $, then $(b^{-1}*a*b)^3 = $

Tags: binary-operations

I got this question from a question paper and the options are as follows :

If $(G,*)$ is a group , $a,b\ \in\  G$, then $(b^{-1}*a*b)^3 = $

a) $(b^{-1})^3*a^3*b^3$

b)$b^{-1}*a^3*b$

c)$b^{-1}*a*b^3$

d)$(b^{-1})^3*a*b^3$

Could anyone explain me what does " $(G,*)$ is a group and $a,b\in G$ " means ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you haven't studied group theory & don't know what a group is?

Comment: It means that $G$ is a group with product indicated by $*$ (so instead of writing $gh$ we write $g*h$).  And of course $a,b\in G$ just means that $a,b$ are two elements of $G$ (possibly the same unless you specify otherwise).

Comment: Note:  I assumed your questions concerned notation only.  If you don't know what a group is then you need to go study that....don't start with this problem, just go read up on the basics.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. I have studied binary operations but didn't came across groups. This question was from university entrance not strictly according to my syllabus. With the notating $g*h$ I can now understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $(G,*)$ is a group

means that $G$ is a set of elements on which a binary operation $*$ is defined, that is, one that satisfies the group axioms.

> $a,b\in G$

means $a$ and $b$ are elements in $G$.

---

To answer the question in the title, notice

\begin{align}
(b^{-1}*a*b)^3&=(b^{-1}*a*b)*(b^{-1}*a*b)*(b^{-1}*a*b)\\
&=b^{-1}*a*b*b^{-1}*a*b*b^{-1}*a*b\\
&=b^{-1}*a*(b*b^{-1})*a*(b*b^{-1})*a*b\\
&=b^{-1}*a*e*a*e*a*b\\
&=b^{-1}*a*a*a*b\\
&=b^{-1}*a^3*b\\
\end{align}

where I denote the identity by $e$.

Comment: How did you know that the binary operation is multiplication ?

Comment: It is not multiplication. It's just an operation

Comment: Then how is $b*b^{-1}=1$ ?

Comment: because $b^{-1}$ is just notation for the inverse of $b$, and I denote the identity by $1$. I recommend you read the [Wikipedia article on groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)), especially the definition part.

Comment: Thank you sir, I now get it :)

Comment: But still, it says "For each a in G, there exists an element b in G, commonly denoted $a^{−1}$ (or −a, if the operation is denoted "+"), such that$ a • b = b • a = e$, where e is the identity element." e=1 for multiplication, is it safe to assume e=1 if no hint is given in question ?

Comment: I just denoted $e$ by $1$. The notation is irrelevant yet I'll change my answer to match wikipedia's notation

Answer (score 1):

G is a group on which these operations will be carried on, so you can write:
$G= (b^{-1}*a*b)^3;$
$= b^{-1}*a*b*b^{-1}*a*b*b^{-1}*a*b$;

note: $b*b^{-1}$ is 1 so you get $b^{-1}*a^3*b$ as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

More generaly, you can prove by induction that for $n\in\Bbb N$

$$(b^{-1}ab)^n=b^{-1}a^nb$$
and for the inductive step write
$$(b^{-1}ab)^{n+1}=(b^{-1}ab)^n(b^{-1}ab)$$
and use the associativity of the law $*$.